# Is there an easy way to manage many rails dev sites on my computer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, rvm

I work on my MacBook Pro. I have many rails projects in ~/dev.

It's like:

- ~/dev/first_project
- ~/dev/second_project
- ~/dev/third_project
- and so on...

Some are rails 2 and others are rails 3 and I use RVM and I use ruby 1.8.7 for all my projects.

When I work for a project I run 'rails s -p 3001' or something like that. Now I'm tired of running the command. I want to use passenger with apache but I don't want to add a configuration for each project.

Is there a way that one configuration works for all projects?

For example, first_project.mylocaldomain.com will work with ~/dev/first_project and .rvmrc in the directory. And so on. So the host name will decide which project and which directory.

I hope I explained well.

Thanks.

Sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

37signals recently released [Pow](http://pow.cx/); does that do anything cool for you? (Asking because I think it might, but I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 2):

Although Passenger is a great solution to this problem, you will need to install a `VirtualHost` entry for each site. This isn't as bad as it sounds if you have a regular structure to your configuration. With a bit of clever scripting you can automatically generate the required files.

A simple alternative is to use the [Passenger Preference Pane](http://www.fngtps.com/passenger-preference-pane) to help manage your Passenger configuration. This avoids having to fuss around with various configuration files by hand. Adding a new directory is a two step process.

The [Pow](http://pow.cx/) software from 37signals is a new kind of approach, but it will knock out your regular Apache instance by re-mapping port 80. If you do any other kind of development work, such as PHP sites, this may not work for you.

Comment: I worked with the Passenger Preference Pane for a long time and it was a great solution.

Comment: I chose alexmuller's answer just because it's more specific. But I really appreciate your elaborate answer.